# Wiremock - How to add --no-request-journal and where to add?

Tags: testing, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I have a Wiremock project. It contains request - response json files, gitlab-ci.yaml and dockerfile.
And also a GUI project related to wiremock project.

Because the old requests are stored to be matched with further requests, the program is throwing heap memory error.

So I need to add --no-request-journal option to make project not store request history.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `--no-request-journal` is a command line option so where you add it will depend on whether you are running wiremock in docker or not.  If you are running wiremock just from the `java` command then you can add the option onto the end like this:

```bash
java -jar wiremock-standalone-3.2.0.jar --no-request-journal
```

Documentation on this and other command line options can be found on the wiremock website - https://wiremock.org/docs/standalone/java-jar/

If you are running wiremock in docker you will need to add the `--no-request-journal` to the end of the docker comand:

```
docker run -it --rm \
  -p "$PORT":"$PORT" \
  --name wiremock \
  -v "$LOCAL_EXTENSIONS_DIR":$DOCKER_EXTENSIONS_DIR \
  -v "$LOCAL_MAPPINGS_DIR":$DOCKER_MAPPINGS_DIR \
  -v "$LOCAL_FILES_DIR":$DOCKER_FILES_DIR \
  wiremock/wiremock:nightly \
  --port "$PORT" --verbose --no-request-journal
```

The above is a snippet from a script file I use to start wiremock in docker and you can see that we are setting a number of command line options for the port, verbose and the no-request-journal.  For reference, the full script can be found [here](https://github.com/leeturner/wiremock-standalone-docker-example/blob/a4b5de845477883fb3f80ac731cc6218d9dc5903/start.sh).  More information on running wiremock in docker can be found here on the wiremock website - https://wiremock.org/docs/standalone/docker/

Once you have added the option using one of the above ways, you should be able to see if this has worked via the output in the console:

```
██     ██ ██ ██████  ███████ ███    ███  ██████   ██████ ██   ██
██     ██ ██ ██   ██ ██      ████  ████ ██    ██ ██      ██  ██
██  █  ██ ██ ██████  █████   ██ ████ ██ ██    ██ ██      █████
██ ███ ██ ██ ██   ██ ██      ██  ██  ██ ██    ██ ██      ██  ██
 ███ ███  ██ ██   ██ ███████ ██      ██  ██████   ██████ ██   ██

----------------------------------------------------------------
|               Cloud: https://wiremock.io/cloud               |
|                                                              |
|               Slack: https://slack.wiremock.org              |
----------------------------------------------------------------

port:                         8080
enable-browser-proxying:      false
disable-banner:               false
no-request-journal:           true
verbose:                      false

extensions:                   response-template,webhook
```

Note the `no-request-journal: true` in the output.

The above examples were using version `3.2.0` of wiremock and the `nightly` docker image.